# R: Create an R function to insert multiple specified lagged or differenced time series into a formula

Tags: r, time-series, formula, linear-regression, lag

The R package `dynlm` offers extended formula notation including two functions very useful for specifying multiple lags: d and L. However these are not exported functions, and only work in the context of the `dynlm()` command as a replacement for `lm()`. The lags accept vectors for the number of lags and produce multiple series if the vectors are longer than 1. This question arises because I do not understand how to hand a function that returns a matrix or tibble of terms to the RHS of a formula in such a way that each column will receive a coefficient when the formula is interpreted, and where there are also other terms. 
One purpose for this is to make it easy to specify models that are different only in the number of lags, a common task.

I've found other packages that let you do something similar, but only with their own estimation function. I want a function that works with any package that evaluates a model expressed as a formula that is linear (at least in the lags).

I would like a set of similar functions L.() and d.() that could be used in a formula in any package that accepts a formula as input, such as packages for general linear models, other time series models like ARIMA or GARCH, and the like, or in more general functions of formulas that can be defined over time series, such as nls.

I’d prefer to be agnostic about the exact specification of the time series, as I am using my data with the tsibble/fable packages but also with other packages like DREGAR, dynlm and rugarch where I have not yet established whether they choke on ts files in tsibble format. However I do not actually know if format agnosticism is possible here. If not, I’d settle for doing my own format conversions.

I would most like it if the functions could be inserted directly into formulas, creating new variables equal to the number of lags, that are treated as linear combinations in the usual way, with each variable getting its own coefficient.

So if

```
ts1 <-  ts(1:4)
```

where 1 is most recent, then `L.(ts1, 0:2)` is

```
ts1_L0 ts1_L1 ts1_L2
1      NA         NA
2       1         NA
3       2          1
4       3          2
```

and

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(4)
extra_var <- 1:4 * (1+ 0.1*y)
```

so that if `form_1 <- as.formula(y ~ L.(ts1, 0:2) + extra_var)` then

`lm(form_1, na.action = na.omit)` would be the linear model of y on the four variables as specified above (and would actually crash since it has five coefficients estimated on two rows of data).

and for

```
ts2 <- ts(2^1:3),
```

`d.(ts1, 1:2)` is similarly

```
ts2_d1 ts2_d2
-1        -3
-2        -6
-41       NA
 NA       NA
```

and should work in formulas in the same way.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think your wanted behavior is possible without either (1) writing a new `lm` function or (2) a wrapper function which evaluates the model and formula in a new environment or (3) a new `as.formula` function which can translate your `L.` function.

Comment: A wrapper function would be fine by me. Though I'm not sure why you couldn't use the env argument in as.formula to get the arguments of L. or d. where they need to be. Aren't these arguments evaluated in the evaluation frame of as.formula (defaulting to the calling environment)?

Comment: Apparently, a simple workaround is possible without the concerns I raised in my comment above. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind the variable names being altered to a function name, then there is quick and dirty work around. The idea is, that in an `lm` call, variable names can be wrapped in functions such as `as.factor()` or `lag()` which change the underlying variable. If you want to create several variables based on a single variable name, like in your case with `L.(var, 0:2)`, then the result of this function needs to be a matrix.

```r
library(dplyr)

L. <- function(x, k) {

  res <- as.matrix(dplyr::bind_cols(lapply(k, function(k) dplyr::lag(x, k))))
  colnames(res) <- paste0("_lag", seq_along(1:ncol(res))-1)
  res

}

lm(cyl ~ L.(mpg, 0:2), mtcars)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = cyl ~ L.(mpg, 0:2), data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>       (Intercept)  L.(mpg, 0:2)_lag0  L.(mpg, 0:2)_lag1  L.(mpg, 0:2)_lag2  
#>         11.334907          -0.245130          -0.015968           0.004683
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

dyn in the dyn package is similar in purpose to dynlm but works with more modeling functions and time series classes.  Quoting from the help file:

> "dyn" currently works with any regression function that makes use of
>   "model.frame" and is written in the style of "lm". This includes "lm",
>   "glm", "loess", "rlm" (from "MASS"), "lqs" (from "MASS"),
>   "MCMCregress" (from "MCMCpack"), "randomForest" (from "randomForest"),
>   "rq" (from "quantreg") and others. The time series objects can be one
>   of the following classes: "ts", "irts", "its", "zoo" or "zooreg".

The dyn help file also discusses how to add additional time series classes without modifying the dyn package itself.

dyn does not provide lag or diff but rather works with the native lag and diff of the time series class you are using.  In particular, zoo supports multi-lag lag and diff functions.

There are 8 demos that come with dyn that illustrate its use with various modelling functions. demo(package = "dyn").

The way it works is that you just preface the modeling function, e.g. lm, with dyn$ .  (This example will give some warnings about combining integer and numeric indexes but it will work anyways.  If you are careful to ensure that all the series you use have the same class of index you can avoid those warnings.)

```
library(dyn)
set.seed(1)

n <- 10
ts1 <-  ts(rnorm(n))
z1 <- zoo(ts1) # so that we can use zoo's multi-lag lag function
y <- rnorm(n)
extra_var <- 1:n * (1+ 0.1*y)

fm2 <- dyn$lm(y ~ lag(z1, 0:-2) + extra_var)
fm1 <- dyn$lm(y ~ lag(z1, 0:-1) + extra_var)
anova(fm1, fm2)
```

As an aside, if you are using dplyr note that dplyr overwrites lag with a version that is incompatible with base lag and will cause numerous time series packages to fail so be sure NOT to have dplyr loaded or in R 3.6 or later you can use library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))